# sql not exists subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, not-exists

I am trying to do some exercises in SQL but I have a big problem to understand some queries.

Here are the tables I am working with:

- `Spectacle` (Spectacle_ID, Titre, DateDéb, Durée, Salle_ID, Chanteur)
- `Concert` (Concert_ID, Date, Heure, Spectacle_ID)
- `Salle` (Salle_ID, Nom, Adresse, Capacité)
- `Billet` (Billet_ID, Concert_ID, Num_Place, Catégorie, Prix)
- `Vente` (Vente_ID, Date_Vente, Billet_ID, MoyenPaiement)

The question is to select all `chanteur` they had at least a concert in all `salles`.

The solution is

```
SELECT Chanteur 
FROM Spectacle t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM Salle u 
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                    FROM Spectacle v
                                    WHERE v.Chanteur = t. Chanteur 
                                      AND u.Salle_ID = v.Salle_ID)
                 )
```

but I can't understand the concept.

Please help with tutorials or some explanations - thanks

Comment: double negation. get all except those where a venue exists that did not have them performing in all of the performances there. I think if you get that in spoken language and logic, you get it in SQL, too. It is less a problem of the syntax, more a problem of getting your head around the specification.

Answer (score 1):

I can see why the solution might be confusing. Returning a result that requires the existence of other rows forces us to visualize the problem vertically instead of horizontally. Hopefully this will help.

We want to only return `Chanteur` that have a `Spectacle` in *every* `Salle`.

Another way to say that is return `Chanteur` that are not missing any `Salle`.

The solution you are asking about addresses the problem in a manner closer to the second form of the question. It will only return `Chanteur` where there does not exist any `Salle` which does not have a corresponding `Spectacle` for that `Chanteur` (not missing any `Salle`).

Another solution would be to use aggregation and `count(distinct Salle_ID)` for each `Chanteur` and compare that to the total number of rows in `Salle`. This would seem more natural when phrasing the problem as *has every* or *has all* instead of *not missing any*.

Comment: Hi thanks for ur answer here is my suggestion   "select chanteur from spectacle group by chanteur having count (distinct  salle_id)>=(select count(sale_id) from salle)"  is this answer correct ?

Comment: @maevabell . . . I view your query as much more intuitive.

Comment: @maevabell that looks correct, much simpler too. Note you can just​ use `=` instead of `>=`

Comment: ok thank you but I still have the same issue with this query  "SELECT Concert_ID, Date
FROM Concert t
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
               (SELECT * FROM Billet u
                WHERE u.Concert_ID=t.Concert_ID
                AND NOT EXISTS 
                             (SELECT * FROM Vente v
                              WHERE u.Billet_ID = v.Billet_ID
                              )
                )
 "        this query is to get ID and date of concerts which there are no tickets to sell    do you have an another simple way to do answer to this ??